# Error playing Audio File From Dispatch | Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
  if (command === "audioclip") {
    var VC = message.member.voiceChannel;
    if (!VC)
        return message.reply("MESSAGE IF NOT IN A VOICE CHANNEL")
VC.join()
    .then(connection => {
        const dispatcher = connection.playFile('https://cdn.glitch.com/14a680b2-22e0-4cd8-a61c-234299e9eaeb%2FTheFatRat%20-%20Fly%20Away%20(Instrumental).mp3?1543059124119');
    dispatcher.on("end", end => {VC.leave()});
    })
    .catch(console.error);
 }
```

It connects but never plays the file. What should I do?

Comment: Can you post the error? At the moment It's very difficult to help if anything is being logged to the console.

Comment: No error is being printed. Bot connects in leaves in 1 second.

Comment: It sounds like the bot is unable to access the file. Now I see you're storing the file on glitch, however when you first make a call to a glitch project asset if the project has gone to sleep it can take several seconds to wake up, thus causing the playFile() to time out.

Comment: So, Should I change my asset location?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the bot is unable to access the file. Now I see you're storing the file on glitch, however when you first make a call to a glitch project asset if the project has gone to sleep it can take several seconds to wake up, thus causing the playFile() to time out.

My recommendation is to sign up for infinityfree with a free subdomain, then upload the file their and copy the link to it. That should work!